# How do create background service for Android in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

Tell me how in Ionic (I use Angular and Capacitor) to create function that, after building project on Android, will work even when application is closed (including after restarting the mobile phone)?
It is required to make periodic POST requests to server and receive data (with open and closed application). If data on server is refreshed, I would like to display LocalNotifications from this background service.

Comment: you can check this tutorial https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-keep-it-running-in-background-using-cordova-and-ionic-native-plugins/#.X8dRhCj0mUk maybe helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is composed of several questions.

## Runing after restart

There is an Ionic plugin that can do this. [Autostart](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/autostart)

## Send request when application is closed

You can use the [Backgroud mode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode) Ionic plugin.

## Display notification

[OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) can display notifications, sent from your backend, on your smartphone. There is also a [Ionic plugin for OneSignal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal). The plugin will take care of being active even if your app is not and will also always be up, even after restart.

Answer (score 3):

Marco's answer is not correct. (I don't have 50 reputation to comment on his answer.. seriously!)
Anyway, background-mode does not allow you to run a background service when the app is closed.
It will work when you app is in the background, but close it and it will stop.
At least that is my experience. I am trying to find an answer to run a service even when the app is closed. Hence I ended up on this thread.
Would love to be proven wrong!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29912557)

Comment: Requiring a reputation to comment on an answer is utterly useless.. Not having the ability to respond to your comment proves the point. (turns out I can comment on my own answer...)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63429715/showing-notifications-in-ionic-app-when-the-app-is-killed-from-foreground what about Background Task, even though I don't really know if I can use it in Capacitor v3

Answer (score 1):

Why don't we try native?

1. Try creating service with reference to native android documentation.
2. I have added a service in ionic and it is working properly.
3. What you have to do is open your your-project/android folder in Android studio.

4.Refer **https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services** for more details.

**[Android Studio shows a different folder structure that a user can understand]**

5. Create a Service **(Right click on app folder, new-->Service in Android Studio)** inside the folder where **MainActivity** is present.
6. Give **the same package name of MainActivity** at top of the new file.
7. Then put the service code and instructions by how to work.

It will definitely work. (**To Check services in MIUI, OPPO, enable AutoStart in app settings inside settings**)